# how to embed LMDB database

Tags: mongodb, installation, lmdb, database

I have heard of `symas lightning memory mapped database`, `LMDB` and went through the available documentations. How to use the database in Visual Studio? Also, is there something like `Collections` of `MongoDB` or `table` of `RDBMS`(I know LMDB is non SQL) in `LMDB`?

Answer (score 0):

LMDB is a key value store, it does not have tables like an RDBMS. An LMDB environment can support multiple database instances within it. You could use each instance to store logically similar keys, just like a mongodb collection.

Comment: what do you mean by database intance

Comment: LMDB has an environment and multiple databases can be defined within it. The [header file](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb/lmdb.h) has more documentation. You can use mdb_env_set_maxdbs to set an upper limit and use mdb_open with separate database names for each instance.